# Has anyone ever mixed strings in a language with position?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, tree, parsing

Let the alphabet $\Sigma$ be extended to include $\bullet$, the concatenation point character.   Define concatenation of such strings to be:
(by example):

$$
s\cdot t = (\omega \bullet \gamma ) \cdot t = \omega t \gamma 
$$

$s$ inherits $t$'s concatenation points obviously.

If $s$ has multiple concatenation points you fill in the concatenation points from left-to-right and if you're out of concatenation points, concatenate $t$ to the end of $s$ to get the result.

So then a syntax tree can be encoded as a member of the the weird algebraic structure.

Then we have a way of concatenating two syntax trees.

Comment: I don't understand your definition. What are $\omega$ and $\gamma$? How do they relate to $s$ and $t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your question right, but this sounds a bit like an extension to Tree Substitution Grammars or Tree Adjoining Grammars (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_adjoining_grammar)

I think a string with concatenation points can be interpreted as a tree with replacable nodes. The concatenation replaces the node and the tree is afterwards interpreted as a strign again. Add a default if there are no concatenation points and you are there.

There is a lot of work on "weird algebraic structures" like this. Check out http://stp.lingfil.uu.se/atanlp/2012/koller.pdf for a quick look if this is what you looking for.